KDE Plasma 5 (Kubuntu 24.04) Desktop / Login Screen Configuration
I need to set the Desktop Configuration in KDE Plasma 5, which corresponds to Kubuntu 24.04. I have a set of 5 monitors, nicely setup within the desktop view, but in the login screen, the Desktop Configuration does not seem to take place, as the order that the monitors are configured in the login screen seems a random.
How can I set the monitors in the login screen identical to the desktop configuration?

Your desktop session does NOT start until after you've logged in, as which user account you'll use has not been selected (the login screen caters for many users, even if your system only has a single login enabled as a default Ubuntu Desktop/flavor install has), so the settings used at the greeter or login screen are DM specific & not related to any user setting. sddm on my box uses the 3 displays connected to my primary graphics card (the other 2 displays on the secondary graphics card on my setup are ignored - I don't always have them turned on so this suits me actually!)

Ok, two completely different things, got it. Personally, I wouldn't complain just having the main monitor switched on at login, while all the others are off. Compared to your setup, I have all the monitors on one graphics card. Now, in sddm there is the option of Apply Plasma Settings..., which also sets the Screen configuration, but it also say, that this only applies to Wayland. Seems though, that x11 is the Default in Kubuntu 24.04. Any idea how to switch from x11 to Wayland?

Seems that it can be installed with plasma-workspace-wayland, but only for testing purposes. Seems it's not supported (https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2497166).
